# What is the purpose of the column length in TINYINT(M)?

Tags: mysql, types

I studied the MySQL documentation and am now unsure what the column length specification (`M`) in TINYINT(M) means. A TINYINT UNSIGNED has a value range of 0 to 255, but `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED` has a range of 0 to 9 ?

Is it better for compression?

Comment: You could try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MySQL documentation about [numeric type attributes:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refrain/5.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be
>   stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column
>   display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column
>   specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to
>   32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are
>   displayed in full using more than three digits.
>
> When used in conjunction with the optional (nonstandard) attribute
>   ZEROFILL, the default padding of spaces is replaced with zeros. For
>   example, for a column declared as INT(4) ZEROFILL, a value of 5 is
>   retrieved as 0005.

That said, you should consider this attribute only if you care about the 0s you could show on the left or if you are in a CLI environment.
Furthermore, if you declare a field as tinyint(2) and the number stored in is 113, all 3 characters will shown (despite what previous answer said)

Comment: +1 This is correct. Also TINYINT(1) is a mnemonic for a boolean. MySQL supports a data type `BOOL` which is an "alias" so to speak. When you define a column as BOOL, it's instantly translated into TINYINT(1), even though the (1) doesn't actually constrain the length or range of values.

Comment: Ok so when the zerofill argument isn't use, there is no need to set a M number.